# JavaScript CSS overide not working when targeting Android API 19

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I am using the following code

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:var con = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); for (var i = 0; i < con.length; ++i)con[i].style.maxWidth='100%'; ");
```

If I target API 18 it works fine however if I target the newest version of Android, API 19, it clears out the entire website I am trying to load and replaces it with text saying "100%". Why does Kit Kat do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an important change with how WebViews handle javascript in KitKat. You should no longer load javascript via the loadUrl() method. Rather, use the new [`evaluateJavascript()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) method:

```
    view.evaluateJavascript(
            "var con = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); " +
            "for (var i = 0; i < con.length; ++i)con[i].style.maxWidth='100%';",
            null);
```

Comment: Is there a reason this changes the screen density of the website?

Answer (score 0):

My previous suggestion was incorrect; so clearing it so as to not mislead, and adding a little extra relevant discussion in it's place that might actually help someone in the future :-)

Krylez is correct - use the `evaluateJavaScript` API to avoid this problem. However, the WebView under the hood will fix this up for you automatically if you set your target SDK to be < 19 and continue to use the legacy `loadUrl` approach with `javascript:` URLs. As soon as you start to target 19 or above, you should switch to `evaluateJavaScript`.

For reference, here's the code that does the fix up: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewChromium.java?av=f#499

Comment: There are other reasons to use evaluateJavascript rather than loadUrl. For instance, calling loadUrl asynchronously on KitKat is now a crash, while evaluateJavascript works fine.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by calling loadUrl asynchronously?

Comment: I completely misspoke. It's a crash to call either of these on a non-UI thread for API 19+ (think it's a warning for lower versions).